# Подбор пароля перебором

Tags: python

Есть набор символов `alphabet='ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'`

Есть пароль `"SZG*SMHF"`.

Нужно вывести список паролей, где звездочка заменяется на символы из набора.

Есть простой Python скрипт?

Comment: Готового нет. Но можешь написать сам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот пример сааааааамого простейшего:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

for ch in ascii_uppercase:
    print(f"SZG{ch}SMHF")
```

и пробуйте сделать сами, а не сразу бежать сюда, если у вас есть хоть какие-нибудь варианты, даже самые безнадёжные, если вы из предоставите, вам помогут с большей вероятностью

Comment: Вариант то хорош, но у него задача сделать подбор с помощью строки `alphabet='ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'`, да и наверняка без сторонних модулей.

Comment: ascii_uppercase эквивалента alphabet, так что разницы не вижу, зачем вбивать строку символов, если это уже давно сделали за вас?